# How to detect word presence and flag the issue in a separate column?

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have many lists, each containing certain words i.e.

```
fruits = ['apple','banana','cherry']
colours = ['red','blue','yellow']
pets = ['dog','cat','fish']
```

I have a column of text in Pandas. I want to check if my text contains any of the words within each list, and create new columns in the same data frame. The column headers are based on the names of the lists:

My table should look like this:

[image]

How should I go about doing this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create dictionary of lists with keys for columns names, then loop and for each list create pattern - join valus by `|` for regex `OR` and for more general solution use word boundary, what is used for [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and last cast boolean mask to integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['This is a red apple','there are not dogs here']})

fruits = ['apple','banana','cherry']
colours = ['red','blue','yellow']
pets = ['dog','cat','fish']

d = {'fruits':fruits, 'colours':colours, 'pets':pets}

for k, v in d.items():
    pat = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(v))
    df[k] = df['Text'].str.contains(pat).astype(int)

print (df)
                      Text  fruits  colours  pets
0      This is a red apple       1        1     0
1  there are not dogs here       0        0     1
```